# GEE: Filtering calendar range using mean tmin Daymet temps when "winter" spans two different years

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am working in Google Earth Engine. I am taking the mean tmin for winter months from Nov to Feb. I am doing this for many years and I have taken this approach for calculating mean tmins over spring season. When I did this for spring, the filtering for months fell on the same year so it was no issue. My question now is I want to filter for winter (November to February), which spans over separate years, is the below code correct or do I need to modify this?

```
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(11,2,'month')) // Nov-Feb (this is where we specify months)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your images as an `ee.ImageCollection`, you can do [a filter date](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-imagecollection-filterdate) like below. This will allow you to set beginning and end dates in different years.

```
ee.ImageCollection('your image collection').filterDate(startdate, enddate)
```